# How to make my android app appear at the TOP of the share via.. list?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

How can I get my android app to appear at the TOP of the Share via.. list, when a share is initiated from another app?

I have seen it done on some apps, e.g. pearltrees, which is always at the top of the list, but can't work out how they did it.

Is it simply alphabetical order, in which case it is the name of the app?

Can this order be changed in any way through programming?

Thanks.

EDIT: I worked it out. This has the desired effect I was looking for:
I used the android:label property in the intent filter e.g.

```
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/name_you_want_to_appear_in_the_list">
```

If you set the string as say "* MyApp *" using characters such as an asterisk, it will go to the top.

Comment: For a good user experience it is probably best not to try to influence the order in any way.

Comment: @Henry Most google apps do this. https://medium.com/@preciselyamal/android-share-sheet-priority-570dddf42cc2

Comment: @amalBit Many apps doing it does not mean it's good.

Comment: @Henry Agree with you that point. But because google apps do this, I assume it is not against the norms. If you had the chance to place your app above all the other competitor apps, would you not use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot be changed by programming. It is based on alphabetical order.. So if you really want to make your app appear first you gotta follow the strategy adopted by Dropbox, Pocket.. etc, ie "Add to Dropbox" "Add to pocket" so that A appears first in the list

Comment: Actually I just worked out how the other app did it. You can set the label using <intent-filter android:label="@string/name_you_want_to_appear_on_list">. If you put the string as say "* MyApp *" using characters such as an asterisk, it will go to the top.

Comment: @capt.swag It shows up as your app name and not your intent filter name. https://medium.com/@preciselyamal/android-share-sheet-priority-570dddf42cc2